Create a STRUCT that returns true for IS NULL if all values are NULL
When I create a column of type STRUCT in a query then IS NULL always returns false, even through all values in the struct are NULL.
Example:
with tmp as(
 SELECT
 STRUCT( NULL as field_1, null as field_2) as a
 )
 SELECT a, a is null as is_null_result from tmp

Result:



a.field_1
a.field_2
is_null_result




null
null
false



Based on How do I check if all fields of a struct are NULL? this is normal behaviour.
However, the Google Analytics export scheme for BigQuery contains a field 'collected_traffic_source' of type RECORD, which contains multiple subfields. Here the schema for this field:
fullname    mode    type    description
collected_traffic_source    NULLABLE    RECORD  
collected_traffic_source.manual_campaign_id NULLABLE    STRING  
collected_traffic_source.manual_campaign_name   NULLABLE    STRING  
collected_traffic_source.manual_source  NULLABLE    STRING  
collected_traffic_source.manual_medium  NULLABLE    STRING  
collected_traffic_source.manual_term    NULLABLE    STRING  
collected_traffic_source.manual_content NULLABLE    STRING  
collected_traffic_source.manual_source_platform NULLABLE    STRING  
collected_traffic_source.manual_creative_format NULLABLE    STRING  
collected_traffic_source.manual_marketing_tactic    NULLABLE    STRING  
collected_traffic_source.gclid  NULLABLE    STRING  
collected_traffic_source.dclid  NULLABLE    STRING  
collected_traffic_source.srsltid    NULLABLE    STRING  

If all subfields of this field are NULL then the query SELECT collected_traffic_source IS NULL from <project>.analytics_123456.events_* returns true.
So is there any way to recreate this behaviour for STRUCTs?
Reason for the question
I am using the field 'collected_traffic_source' in quite a few of my queries, in combination with 'is null', 'ifnull' or window functions that use 'ignore nulls'.
But last Friday Google added new subfields to collected_traffic_source (e.g. mnanual_source_platform) which caused problems because the data structure of my derived tables did not match anymore. Therefore I adjusted my query such that it does not directly use the field 'collected_traffic_source' anymore but instead I created a struct that uses only the subfields that were used before the change. The idea was to keep the data structure the same as before and just ignore the new subfields for now.
Before:
SELECT collected_traffic_source from <project>.analytics_123456.events_* 

After (simplified):
SELECT
STRUCT(
      collected_traffic_source.manual_source as source,
      collected_traffic_source.manual_medium as medium
    ) as collected_traffic_source
 FROM <project>.analytics_123456.events_* 

But using IS NULL on this STRUCT always returns false, which is different behaviour from using the original field 'collected_traffic_source' and thus causes problems in subsequent queries.
Therefore I am searching for a way to create a STRUCT that behaves exactly the same way as the original field.
The BigQuery documentation for IS NULL or STRUCT do not have any info on the NULL handling of STRUCTS. There also seems to be no way to create a RECORD field through SQL, according to the docs RECORDS are accessed through STRUCTs.

What I think I want you to consider is the distinction between a column in a table where the column is "NULL" (i.e. there is no value for the column) vs a value that is a STRUCT which contains fields whose values are NULL.   For the former ...  column IS NULL is true ... the column contains no value.  However for the later, column IS NULL is false ... the columnb contains a value (i.e. there IS  a struct there) ... but the values of its fields are NULL.
